# Ember Handlerbars @ How to access inner dict values via parent index?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

@index, index is not working inside templates. I dont know exactly. Therefore, I have moved to {{_view.contentIndex}} for getting index value.

**Question No 1:**

How to access second_dict values via parent index ?

Let say, I have two dicts

```
first_dict = [{"name":"x"},{"name":"y"},{"name":"z"}]
second_dict = [{"name":"x"},{"name":"y"}]


{{#each first in first_dict}}
   {{_view.contentIndex}} # output as 0,1,2
   ???{{second_dict._view.contentIndex.name}} # how to access second_dict value based on parent index ?
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `{{get}}` helper and custom `{{to-string}}` helper:

```
{{#each first_dict as |first index|}}
  Second dict value: {{get (get second_dict (to-string index)) 'name'}}
{{/each}}
```

[`{{get}}` helper documentation.](http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/templates/the-get-helper/)

- [Working demo.](http://ember-twiddle.com/6b1b71318880f85ef868)
- [Full code behind demo.](https://gist.github.com/Kuzirashi/6b1b71318880f85ef868)

Comment: Hi, i am getting the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'helper' of undefined

Comment: Make sure you're using latest Ember + Ember CLI version.

Comment: I will check it out and get back to you !! am sorry, if i am late

Comment: Both askers and answerers need patience here on stackoverflow. Please, take your time. I've written you a comment to check my answer, because I've posted, then deleted my answer and then I undeleted it. I wanted you to get notification.

Comment: using ember-cli 1.13.8
ember 0.2.3
Still getting the same error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'helper' of undefined

Comment: You sure you have correct versions? When you open console you should get all versions of libraries. Maybe run: `ember generate helper to-string` and then copy only body of function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89834/discussion-between-user2224250-and-daniel-kmak).